# How to update vue.js v-data-table and update column value with new text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

New to Vue and I have a v-data-table with a column I want updatable but not sure how!
I can pass any/all of the property values but can't seem to figure out how to pass the updated text when the user changes it.

How do I get that value when I have multiple rows with this column? I can do it for one field, but this is in a table with many rows.

here is the column

```html
<td>
  <v-text-field 
   v-model="props.item.productAnnotation" 
   // how do I pass the new text into the first parameter?
   @input="inputAnnotation(??????, props.item.id)" 
   :disabled="!editMode" 
   :readonly="!editMode">
  </v-text-field>
</td>
```

and here is the method

```js
inputAnnotation(text, recordProductId) {
  axios.patch('/api/RecordProducts/' + recordProductId, [{
    'op': 'replace',
    'path': '/annotation',
    'value': text
  }]).then(function(response) {
    // Show response
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Show error
    console.log(error);
  })
},
```

Comment: You already have it. It's bound by `v-model`. It's in `this.item.annotation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (depending on the source)

```
@input="inputAnnotation($event.target.value, props.item.id)"
```

or

```
@input="inputAnnotation($event, props.item.id)"
```

And also remove your v-model and replace it with a bind to setting the value

```
:value='props.item.productAnnotation'
```

`$event` contains the data sent with the emitted message `input`.

`v-model` will handle this for you by assigning the value to a data property though.  v-model is just sugar for connecting `:value` and `@input` to a common property, and handles a few extra edge cases.

In a nutshell `v-model` creates a `v-bind:value` and sends changes from its bound data to the `value` property of the child component.  It then creates `@input` and listens for the event to be emitted.  When received, it updates the property.  This is done so the parent can `own the data`.  The child cannot update the property, so must emit an event for the parent to change it.  As strange as it may seem, it creates a very clean architecture where only the owner can update the value.  And this is one of the core tenants of Vue.

Comment: It seesm that $event.target.value is undefined, but $event passes the new text.

Comment: It depends on the emit source.  I will update solution.

Comment: do you have any idea why I'm getting a error in the console when I add/remove characters from this field? The error message says "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'productAnnotation' of object '#<Object>'""

Comment: Try `@input="event=>inputAnnotation(event, props.item.id)" ` and let us know if that solves your issue.  I don't see where `productAnnotation` is even defined...

Comment: If you comment out your axios call, does the error go away?

Comment: No. I tried commenting out the axios call and it still errors

Comment: Oh, change `   v-model="props.item.productAnnotation" to `:value='props.item.productAnnotation'`

Comment: You have now replaced v-model with a :value and @input...  I updated solution, again...

Comment: yup! that worked! Can you explain a little more. I'm very new to Vue.js, came from a ASP.Net MVC background

Comment: Here is a link, and I will summarize it in the solution.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components